# ScriptSharp compilation with NAnt script

Tags: nant, script#

We've recently added the excellent script# to our project. Currently we have it so that our VS build simply copies the compiled .js file from the output directory to the scripts directory of our web app.

We've decided to make it a permanent feature and so would like to make it so that the .js file gets generated as part of our web build NAnt script to ensure that it's always up to date. Is there any way to do this nicely or do I need to call MSBuild from my NAnt script specifying the .csproj file to run the compilation?

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't likely the full answer (given I don't have experience with NAnt), but I'll offer it anyway, as it may help.

A script# csproj is very much like any other csproj relying on msbuild. If you've got some way to integrate other msbuild projects into your NAnt build script, the same model should ideally apply to script# projects as well.

In the version of script# that is in the github repository, a web project can add a reference to a script# project (thereby becoming dependent on the script# project), and include an msbuild deploy task, that will copy over scripts from the built script# project into the web project. You can see this in action in the Todo sample (https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/samples/Todo)

Comment: How do I get hold of this NuGet package: `<package id="ScriptSharp.Runtime" version="0.8" targetFramework="net45" />` ?